# Need help for ftp files status

Tags: powershell

i have been looking for a way to know the status of my ftp files, there are few log files are being uploading on my ftp server after every 15mints, but few times it fails to upload i just want an alert when ever a file fails to upload.
following code has been tired

```
function update {

    $ftprequest = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create("ftp://ftpsite.com/Script_Apps/install_firefox.exe")
    $ftprequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::GetDateTimestamp
    $response = $ftprequest.GetResponse().StatusDescription
    $tokens = $response.Split(" ")
    $code = $tokens[0]

    $localfile = (Get-Item "$dir\Apps\install_firefox.exe").LastWriteTimeUtc

    if ($tokens -gt $localfile) {

        write-host "Updating Firefox Installer..."
        $File = "$dir\Apps\install_firefox.exe"
        $ftp = "ftp://ftpsite.com/Script_Apps/install_firefox.exe"
        $webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
        $uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp)
        $webclient.DownloadFile($uri, $File)

        "Updated Firefox" >> $global:logfile

        mainmenu

    }

    else {
        Write-Host "Local Copy is Newer."
        sleep 3
        mainmenu
    }

}
```

Comment: in other words i need to generate alert if file is not uploaded

Comment: Where are you uploading a file in this code?  This code looks like code to download a file. Can you tell me which line uploads the file?

Comment: actully this is a sample code i was mistakenly used this code, the thing is i need a code from which i can gernate an alert when it file not uploaded

Comment: OK, same idea.  Just take my answer and apply it to wherever you are downloading or uploading a file to an FTP server and it will do the same thing.

Comment: that code also tired form some alterations but no succeeded

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume this line deals with downloading/uploading files for your FTP site.

```
    $ftp = "ftp://ftpsite.com/Script_Apps/install_firefox.exe"
    $webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    $uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp)
    $webclient.DownloadFile($uri, $File)
```

If so, then we can lookout for errors and do something when one occurs with `try{}catch{}` blocks.

You can put any code inside a `try` block, and when it hits a terminating error it will capture the error as `$Error[0]` which we can reference in a `catch` block.

```
try{
    $ftp = "ftp://ftpsite.com/Script_Apps/install_firefox.exe"
    $webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    $uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp)
    $webclient.DownloadFile($uri, $File)
}
catch{
   #Write out an error to the screen 
   "failed to download file $($ftp).  `n--Ran into error $($Error[0].Exception.Message)"

   #Todo - send a notification
}
```

This will give a result like this, when it fails to download.

```
Failed to download file ftp://ftpsite.com/Script_Apps/install_firefox.exe.  
---Ran into error Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): 
    "Unable to connect to the remote server"
```

Then, you can determine the best way to send a notification to suit your needs.  There's way's to [send e-mail from PowerShell](https://www.pdq.com/blog/powershell-send-mailmessage-gmail/), [or Tweets](https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2010/06/powershell-send-tweet/), or even [using a Push message to the Pushbullet app on your phone!](https://foxdeploy.com/functions/powerbullet-pushbullet-for-powershell/)

Comment: thanks but this is not my actual code can i have your email address so that i will share my code to you from which i am uploading my files to ftp server i will be very thank full to you if you help me

Comment: Please sanitize your code and remove the private bits and edit it into your post, Stack Overflow posts shouldn't end with a private email discussion.